# How can I get the text of a selected option with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, select

I have a form in an ASP.NET MVC project which has a select drop down list akin to the following:

```
<select>
  <option value="ee5711b9-ec86-4378-a975-ae10a4ebedbc">Volvo Account</option>
  <option value="0dc0e9d8-2245-43de-81a9-5b94c19646fa">Saab Account</option>
  <option value="f9a05ef6-9ca6-4eeb-9e04-79726a62b38c">Mercedes Account</option>
  <option value="1c5c2e43-06d6-4b7d-916a-231be535a608">Audi Account</option>
</select>
```

In a later page in the project I need to do something with the GUID identifier, but first I need to prompt the user for confirmation. Obviously the GUID is useless to them and they'd like to see the friendlier name (i.e., "Volvo Account").

But when I drill into the FormCollection values, all I can get is the value, not the text of the selected option This makes sense given the design goals, but how can I also POST over the text value?

I can think of some workarounds (setting a hidden field with JavaScript, doing a lookup after the fact with the GUID and the same method by which I populated this, etc.) but is there any intrinisc way to do this I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no intrinsic way to do this, JavaScript is really your best option.

Add an "onchange" event handler to your SELECT that sets the value of a hidden input to the display value of the selected OPTION.

Comment: What if the value doesn't ever change? I don't agree with it but the way the client wants it, the first value in the list is a valid one (so they can click right through if they don't want to change it)

Comment: You can set the value of the hidden input to match the value of your SELECT input in your view pretty easily and let the JavaScript wireup handle changes.  Of you can have a page-ready script run and set the hidden input to the selected value once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using hidden fields:

```
<select>
    <option value="ee5711b9-ec86-4378-a975-ae10a4ebedbc">Volvo Account</option>
    <option value="0dc0e9d8-2245-43de-81a9-5b94c19646fa">Saab Account</option>
    <option value="f9a05ef6-9ca6-4eeb-9e04-79726a62b38c">Mercedes Account</option>
    <option value="1c5c2e43-06d6-4b7d-916a-231be535a608">Audi Account</option>
</select>
...
<input type="hidden" name="Options[0].Key" value="ee5711b9-ec86-4378-a975-ae10a4ebedbc" />
<input type="hidden" name="Options[0].Value" value="Volvo Account" />
<input type="hidden" name="Options[1].Key" value="0dc0e9d8-2245-43de-81a9-5b94c19646fa" />
<input type="hidden" name="Options[1].Value" value="Saab Account" />
...
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(..., IDictionary<string, string> options)
{
    string selectedValue = ...;
    string selectedText = options[selectedValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle Drop Downs / Select Boxes in MVC with a static property within a Collection class in Models.

Example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SomeProject.Models
{
    public class Collections
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> AccountType = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "", "" },
            { "ee5711b9-ec86-4378-a975-ae10a4ebedbc", "Volvo Account" },
            { "0dc0e9d8-2245-43de-81a9-5b94c19646fa", "Saab Account" },
            { "f9a05ef6-9ca6-4eeb-9e04-79726a62b38c", "Mercedes Account" },
            { "1c5c2e43-06d6-4b7d-916a-231be535a608", "Audi Account" }
        };
    }
}
```

Then I would render the DropDown in the View like:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("AccountType", new SelectList(SomeProject.Models.Collections.AccountType, "Key", "Value", Convert.ToString(ViewData["AccountType"])), "", new { tabindex = "3", @class = "dropdown" }) %>
```

Now that Collection is available to your entire application.  You can grab whatever user-friendly name you'd like via:

```
SomeProject.Models.Collections.AccountType[ViewData["AccountType"]]
```

You could even render the collection out to the View if you desire.

Hope that helps.